# PHP Router/Dispatcher, dependency injection, passing dependencies

Tags: php, dependency-injection

So I'm creating my own little framework to learn design patterns and I think I've got a decent Router/Dispatcher framework going and I'm writing a little MVC framework to handle the requests. My R/D looks something like this:

```
$router = new Router();
$dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
$request = new Request();
$response = new Response();
$router->addRoute(new Route('user', 'view', 'UserController'));

$route = $router->route($request, $response);
$dispatcher->dispatch($route, $request);
```

Now my model objects can pull data from a couple different data sources (mysql, oracle), so I'm trying to figure out the best way to pass instantiated data sources to those objects without coupling them. In a related question I was pointed in the direction of using a DIC but I'm still not sure where to instantiate it and how to give my model objects access to it. I'm also a little fuzzy on how that decouples things. My current understanding of using a DIC would be to add something like this:

```
$oic = new IOC();
$oic->register('mysql_db', new DBMysql(...));
$oic->register('oracle_db', new DBOracle(...));

class UserController
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $user = User::fetch($oic->get('mysql_db'), $user_id);
        ...
    }
}
```

With that example I'm still fuzzy on how to get the $oic from creation down to the controller execute. It also seems too tightly coupled. For example, if I have a 100 different controllers referencing the mysql_db and I want to switch them to a different data source, then i'm updating a 100 controller classes with the same info.

I was considering changing my router route to accept a db parameter, but then what if I have a controller that needs to reference more than one db connection (I will).

**UPDATE**

I ended up just changing my router route to pass parameters to the controller, so with my crude example if I had user info stored in a MySQL db but the user's dept info stored in an Oracle db, it would look something like this:

```
$db_mysql = new DBMysql();
$db_oracle = new DBOracle();
...
$router->addRoute(new Route('user', 'view', 'UserController', array($db_mysql, $db_oracle)));
...
class UserController
{
    private $db_user = null;
    private $db_dept = null;

    public function __construct(DBInterface $db_user, DBInterface $db_dept)
    {
        $this->db_user = $db_user;
        $this->db_dept = $db_dept;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $user = User::fetch($this->db_user, $user_id);
        $dept = Dept::fetch($this->db_dept, $user->dept_id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Look into using a [singleton](http://phpadvocate.com/blog/2011/04/php-using-a-singleton-pattern-with-oop/) pattern.

Comment: @Dropzilla proposing the singleton pattern over dependency injection without justification is stupid.

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli you have a valid point, not sure I would have used the word "stupid", but I agree that validating comments can be helpful for the person asking the questions. In regard to using a singleton vs dependency injection (DI), I'd like to hear why you feel the DI pattern is better in this instance? In the original question fwrawx stated he will have controllers that reference more than one db connection. I would argue it may be easier to maintain a singleton with both connections rather than using DI and config files.

Comment: @Dropzilla yeah sorry it was a bit harsh. But I'm not suggesting DI is better. It's just that this is a question about DI, I don't see a reason to suggest using another pattern without justification. It's like a question about Zend Framework: suggesting to use Symfony doesn't make sense

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli good point, I agree with you. fwrawx the only reason I suggested singleton vs DI is I like to work with as little code as possible and I felt that using a singleton in this instance may prevent you from having to maintain two separate dependency files. However, as Matthieu pointed out your question was about DI so I hope I have not confused you. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Don't inject the container, that will lead you to another pattern which is the **Service locator** pattern.

This is considered an anti-pattern because your code (controller) will depend on the container.

If, in your controller, you want a `DBObject`, then inject a `DBObject`.

```
// Configuration of your application
$oic = new IOC();
$oic->register('db', new DBMysql(...));
// or
// $oic->register('db', new DBOracle(...));

// Controller
class UserController
{
    private $db;

    public function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $user = User::fetch($this->db, $user_id);
        ...
    }
}
```

With this design, the controller don't care what DB implementation it will use (oracle or mysql). It can be changed in the "configuration" part of your application.

---

Now to inject the `db` object to the controller, you have several possibilities.

I suggested you have a look at existing DI containers like Symfony or [PHP-DI](http://mnapoli.github.io/PHP-DI/) (disclaimer: I work on that one).

Basically they allow you to define what should be given in the parameters of `UserController::__construct`.

Comment: Also have a look at https://github.com/mnapoli/PHP-DI-ZF1, this is the integration in the MVC part of the container PHP-DI (integration in the router/dispatcher)

Comment: I tried injecting the container and then realized like you have said, it just ends up being a service locator. I ended up ditching the container and modifying my route class to accept an array of parameters to pass on to the controller constructor like you are suggesting. I'm still not convinced this is the best approach but for now it works.